# My manager wont increase my salary as promised

Tags: salary, manager, turkey

I live in Turkey. I am a software engineer with 4 years experience. I joined my company about 1.5 year ago. My manager and I talked about my salary which was very low he offered me at first. He promised me that he would increase my salary after a year.

Unfortunately, I got cancer twice. I needed my family support to fight it so I moved to my family to a small city. Software engineering is not trendy in my city and companies won't pay good money. Now, my salary is not good enough to support me anymore. My job doesn't satisfy me anymore either. My manager does not know anything about software development and won't let me do things the way I would like to.

How can I ask him that I am not satisfied with my salary and position? I don’t want to lose my job, but can’t focus on my work while stuck in this situation.

Comment: In which country do you currently live? Having a location helps us make the advice more geared towards your situation.

Comment: I don't know what your home country is but you probably, cannot simply "move to EU/US" without a job and a company willing to sponsor your VISA. To quit and THEN start searching? Definitely not a good move.

Comment: The promise your manager made, do you have any record of it, in an email for example?

Comment: @Erik edited my question.

Comment: At the moment, it's unclear what you're actually asking here. Your title and first paragraph refer to a promised pay rise, but the rest seem to be about your general dissatisfaction with your job. Please try and edit this so it's just one question, but note that [questions asking for advice on a specific choice are off-topic here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change#2695).

Comment: @Kozaky unfortunately I don’t.

Comment: @PhilipKendall you are right. I could have explained it in a better way. I edited my question.

Comment: I would focus on the promise of the salary increase first. If there's no paper thread though, it'd be easy for the manager to say that the salary increase was never promised.

Answer (score 5):

If the market rate in your area is higher than what you are receiving or if the skills you are bringing on board are critical, you might have a better chance of getting a raise. If the promise is in writing that could also help but if it was just a verbal "yeah, sure, you will get an increase", you might end up having a hard time.

In any case, the common advice goes not to quit your job until you have another one.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I ask him that I am not satisfied with my salary and position?

Schedule a meeting with your manager and discuss your concerns; they are here to listen and help you. I'm sure there are other articles discussing [how to ask for a raise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/119129/how-can-i-communicate-to-my-employer-the-urgency-of-a-raise-request/119131#119131).

As mentioned in the comments, if you don't have evidence then this discussion with your manger will serve as a starting point and if you are performing well your manager will compensate you accordingly depending on company policies and current fund allocations.